# A better way to construct a datetime with higher precision than milliseconds

Tags: datetime, constructor, precision

I have just gone through an **unexpectedly convoluted** process to define datetimes.

The underlying data has a **better precision than milliseconds**.

I ended up constructing an **intermediate datetime** to the nearest second, reading it's value in **ticks** (10 000 to the millisecond), adjusting the ticks then creating the datetime that I **actually wanted**.

I expected constructors that took **seconds as doubles** and that takes a string date/time **format specifier**.  Neither seems to exist.

**Anybody got a good alternate approach?**

Comment: FWIW, I agree with you. It would have been quite easy for the .Net designers to include constructors for the TimeSpan class that took `double` parameters. However, it's easy enough to write these yourselves (as you realized).

Comment: Yes you're right it's not that hard.  It's the fact that's it's needed that surprises me.  We have a type that has a precision down to 100 nanoseconds (7 digits after the point) and no native way to tap into that.  I don't understand the design of the constructors.  Would you have left a hole like that?

Comment: I agree.  The ticks constructor is complete, as it can be used to construct every conceivable value of a DateTime.  On the other hand, the year, month, day, etc. style constructors are incomplete, as it cannot construct every conceivable value of a DateTime, and can only construct values whose time falls on whole milliseconds.  They absolutely should have made the seconds parameter a double or added a similar constructor with nanosecond precision.  They provided piece-wise constructors for everything down to milliseconds, but then made no piece-wise constructor for nanoseconds.  Lame.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to instantiate a `DateTime` based on fractions of a second. The closest you can get, as you have discovered, is using ticks. A function like this should at least save you from having to create multiple `DateTime`s in every case.

```
public DateTime DateTimeFromFractionalSeconds(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, double seconds)
{
    return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute).AddTicks((long)(seconds * 1000000000));
}
```

You're right that the designers could have included such a constructor. However, the `DateTime` class is not based around seconds any more than it's around minutes. I realize that you want fractional seconds, but can you truly make the case that fractional seconds would be more legitimate than fractional minutes? Or hours? The `DateTime` class is based around ticks. That is the smallest indivisible unit of measure that it deals with, which is why the most granular constructor is represented in ticks.

Comment: I used that in my solution.  It's a pretty stupid approach though.  I have a datetime in years, months... fractional seconds.  I have to convert that to ticks to then create the datetime I really want using ticks.  A truly idiotic procedure.

Comment: No that's not a solution.  I already did that.  I was looking for a better way, or maybe some undocumented approach that did what I expected.

Comment: @Mike: What you're asking for doesn't exist. "It doesn't exist" is a perfectly legitimate answer to a question, and is correct in this case. Given that this is the only answer that is correct and provides potentially useful code, I would appreciate it if you would mark it as accepted.

Comment: I can make the case. Suppose they had stopped the overloads with a constructor "DateTime(year,month,day,hour,minute)", which allows you to specify time in whole minutes. That would mean that anyone who wants to specify DateTime with a precision greater than whole minutes would have to resort to specifying the whole thing completely in ticks, or with your hack. The fact that they stopped at millisecond precision is not any less stupid or arbitrary.  The fact remains that there is no piece-wise constructor capable of instantiating every possible DateTime value (i.e. with nanosecond precision).

Comment: @Triynko: The case I asked him to make was that fractional seconds was somehow more legitimate than fractional minutes. You make the case yourself that the line is arbitrary ("stupid" seems unnecessarily degrading; what, exactly, was "stupid" about the choice?).

Why *should* there be a piecewise constructor that allows you to specify every one of the units? The base unit of the `DateTime` is ticks, and there's a constructor for that.

Comment: Um, because why create a constructor that just accepts whole years?  Ticks makes sense, because it allows you specify every possible value a DateTime can hold.  A constructor that just accepts years cannot.  It can only create dates that fall on Jan 1.  Or why stop with an overload that's just years and months?  My point is they stopped arbitrarily at milliseconds, which was a stupid decision, IMO, because  why create a piece-wise constructor that doesn't reach the full precision?  Full precision could have been reached by either adding nanoseconds or making the seconds parameter fractional.

Comment: And the logic behind making seconds fractional, rather than minutes, is that fractional portion of seconds is actually measured in base 10 (so it makes sense as a decimal), whereas fractional minutes are actually seconds which are essentially base 60, and therefore don't make sense as a decimal. Fractional seconds use base 10: milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, etc. It's the most natural way of doing it other than specifying seconds and nanoseconds. In any case, that would allow it create precise times. As it stands now, the piece-wise constructors are useless for creating precise times.

Comment: In fact, a single precision float would be sufficient as only 9 significant digits are required to represent 59.0000001 (59 seconds with one 100-nanosecond increment).  "If an IEEE 754 single precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 9 significant decimal and then converted back to single, then the final number must match the original." Your answer is probably the most efficient method of translating floating-point seconds into a DateTime using it's available constructors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this date time to time how long it takes to run your code, you'd be much better off using the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) stopwatch class.  It uses a high precision timer that isn't available to the DateTime object. If you aren't timing how long something takes between 2 points, and just want the current time, to something more precise than milliseconds, I think that you are going a bit overboard, and may not need all that precision, or that you the extra precision is meaningless.

Comment: You are entirely entitled to your opinion about precise timing, but you should keep it to yourself.  Without knowledge of the sitution you can easily say something wrong.  (Hint discriminating between times that are already logged against the same clock but are very close to one another.)  Yes I've used much more precise timers since .NET 1, they are really good, but they are no use here.